# Best Practice for Batch Processing with RabbitMQ

Tags: python-3.x, rabbitmq, etl

I'm looking for the best way to preform ETL using Python.

I'm having a channel in RabbitMQ which send events (can be even every second). 
I want to process every 1000 of them.
The main problem is that RabbitMQ interface (I'm using pika) raise callback upon every message.
I looked at Celery framework, however the batch feature was depreciated in version 3.

What is the best way to do it? I thinking about saving my events in a list, and when it reaches 1000 to copy it to other list and preform my processing. However, how do I make it thread-safe? I don't want to lose events, and I'm afraid of losing events while synchronising the list.

It sounds like a very simple use-case, however I didn't find any good best practice for it.

Comment: I find it a bad Design to do it like that! It doesn't seem efficient. why you design it like that ? couldn't you use Multithreading and get a subscriber to subscribe for an event in an independant thread an process every event ?

Comment: Here is the use case: I'm calculating aggregations on the events and save the data to database. So It's much faster to aggregate 1000 events in python runtime and then just update the database, other then 1000 times update the database (and it will be multiple updates).

Comment: you can listen to all the evetns and when you reach 1000 you give it to a handler to store them in db, you can use multithreading

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do I make it thread-safe?

How about set consumer `prefetch-count=1000`. If a consumer's `unack` messages reach its prefetch limit, rabbitmq will not deliver any message to it.

Don't `ACK` received message, until you have 1000 messages, then copy it to other list and preform your processing. When your job done, `ACK` the last message, and [all message before this message will be `ACK` by rabbitmq server](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html#consumer-acks-multiple-parameter).

But I am not sure whether large prefetch is the best practice.

Comment: This approach will need some kind of timeout where you are collecting messages. Without it you can stuck for arbitrary amount of time with unprocessed messages while wait for exactly 1000 of them

Comment: Yes, you would need to use the [inactivity_timeout](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/adapters/blocking.html#pika.adapters.blocking_connection.BlockingChannel.consume) when calling consume.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code for batch processing with pika.

```
class RabbitMQBatchConsumer():
def __init__(self, USERNAME, PASSWORD, HOST, BATCH_SIZE, QUEUE):
    credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
    parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(HOST, 5672, '/', credentials)
    self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
    self.channel = self.connection.channel()
    self.messages= []
    self.batch_size= BATCH_SIZE
    self.queue = QUEUE
    
def start_consuming(self):
    self.channel.basic_consume(queue=self.queue, on_message_callback=self.on_message)
    self.channel.start_consuming()
    
def on_message(self, unused_channel, basic_deliver, properties, body):
    self.messages.append((basic_deliver, properties, body))
    if len(self.messages) == self.batch_size:
        self.process()
        
def process(self):
    # IMPLEMENT YOUR PROCESS HERE WITH self.messages
    try:
        for i in range(len(self.messages)):
            msg = self.messages.pop()
            self.channel.basic_ack(msg[0].delivery_tag)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

After that you just need to create instance of this class and call `start_consuming` function.

```
batch_consumer = RabbitMQBatchConsumer(USERNAME, PASSWORD, HOST, BATCH_SIZE, QUEUE)
batch_consumer.start_consuming()
```

Comment: This approach will need some kind of timeout where you are collecting messages. Without it you can stuck for arbitrary amount of time with unprocessed messages while wait for `len(self.messages)` to reach `self.batch_size`

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you should not "batch" messages from RabbitMQ unless you really have to. The most efficient way to work with messaging is to process each message independently.

If you **need** to combine messages in a batch, I would use a separate data store to temporarily store the messages, and then process them when they reach a certain condition. Each time you add an item to the batch, you check that condition (for example, you reached 1000 messages) and trigger the processing of the batch.

This is better than keeping a list in memory, because if your service dies, the messages will still be persisted in the database.

Note : If you have a single processor per queue, this can work without any synchronization mechanism. If you have multiple processors, you will need to implement some sort of locking mechanism.

Comment: There are many use cases in which batch processing can be useful. in data science for instance there is a huge performance gain to make predictions in batch.

Comment: Why is it better to use a separate data store to temporarily store the messages, compared to using rabbit as "data store" by processing in batches?

Comment: Robycool how does one manage batch processing?